# Prometheus Query example for Flink metrics

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus

Need a help. Does any one of you have an example Prometheus query for following metrics. These are gaugue metrics, I am not sure, which operator to use for these metrics.

flink_taskmanager_job_task_numRecordsInPerSecond
flink_jobmanager_job_fullRestarts/flink_jobmanager_job_fullRestarts
flink_taskmanager_job_task_isBackPressured
flink_jobmanager_job_numberOfFailedCheckpoints
flink_jobmanager_job_lastCheckpointDuration

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good if you look some official Prometheus API [examples](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/) and Grafana [docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/) if you use it.

Here the query that I use :

`sum by(job_name)(flink_jobmanager_job_totalNumberOfCheckpoints{job_name=~"myJobName_.+"})`